# Is it possible to post a status to your facebook wall through a url query?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, twitter

In twitter it's possible by doing:
https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=THIS IS MY MESSAGE IT NEEDS ENCODING

Then it will bring up twitter with that message, and let you choose whether or not you want to tweet it.

I was wondering if there's a similar way with facebook posting a message through a link?

Thanks!
-Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - and you don't need an app registered to do so!  The only down side, is that you *have* to include a URL.

The query is simply:

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<URL>&t=<text>
```

For example - https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fshkspr.mobi%2Fblog%2F&t=Check%20out%20this%20cool%20blog

Both the URL and the text will have to be URL encoded.  As I said, it won't work without a URL.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have the [Feed Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog) that does the same. But of course you must have an app registered on http://developers.faceboof.com/apps.

URL Redirection:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?
  app_id=145634995501895
  &display=popup
  &caption=An%20example%20caption 
  &link=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fdialogs%2F
  &redirect_uri=https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer
```

(replace `app_id` and `redirect_uri` with that of yours)

For the list of available parameters, check [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog#params)